# can we generate clickable jfree charts with tooltip using jsp and servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jfreechart

I am able to generate stacked bar charts (whatever charts i want) in my application using jsp and servlet.

I need to add tooltips when i hover over the bars and make it clickable so that it calls some mouse click event.

I have gone through chart panels and mouseclick events but want to make sure whether it works in jsp and servlet first.

yeah i know in code we write as saveaspng so it shows the output as image only, can anyone please tell me whether is it possible have clickable output on jsp page using servlet output ??

i know this is possible in swing i have another application which can do this.

note:same is possible in google charts (it uses javascript so no relation between my question and google charts but just for knowledge sake i am mentioning here),but stacked bar considers the whole bar as same no clickable event separatley(this is another issue).

Comment: You ought to look around for javascript charting solutions.

Comment: can you please tell me whether is it possible to do that with jsp and servlet ?

Comment: To make anything do something on the page when clicked without submitting a form and going to another page requires javascript or Flash. You can't do it in JSP alone. JSP only runs on the server so it doesn't know when the user clicks something unless javascript is communicating with it via Ajax.